# Running out of memory in C++ due to making new objects

Tags: c++, object, nodes, heap-memory, montecarlo

So I am trying to implement a Monte Carlo search tree for an Othello game. I have a root node and children nodes, where 'x' is a child of 'y' if you can move from 'y' to 'x' in a single legitimate move.

At each node I store a 'Board' object which holds all of the board information, such as what value each tile is. The first issue I had was that if I changed the board object of a child node, it changed the values for the parent node as well. I fixed this by creating a 'NEW' Board object for every child node, but this resulted in excessive memory being used when I ran the simulation a few thousand times, to the point that I ran out of memory.

I am just wandering if there is either a way to alter the board information in the child nodes without it changing the board information of the parents, or if there is a better way to store the board information at each node instead of creating a new Board object for every node.

If anything needs clarifying just comment below, thanks for reading!

EDIT :

```
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfChildren; x += 1) {

        // Resets *currentBoard to the same state as the node being expanded
        Board *currentBoard = nodeToExpand->getCurrentBoard();

        // Retrives the board value information
        int** temporaryBoardValues = currentBoard->getBoardValues();

        // Makes a new board object with the previous parameters
        Board *temporaryBoard = new Board(blockSize, boardSize, offset);

        // Sets the new board values to the same as the old ones
        temporaryBoard->setBoardValues(temporaryBoardValues);

        // Creates a clone of that board state
        // Board *temporaryBoard = cloneBoard(*currentBoard);

        // Creates a node with the cloned board state, setting the parent to be the node being expanded. 
        // Assigns it one of the available moves
        // Produces the array of child nodes
        myChildren[x] = new Node(nodeToExpand, temporaryBoard, availableMoves[x], currentPlayer);

        //delete temporaryBoard;
    }
```

Small code snippet. Its the part at which I create a new Board object that uses up all of the memory.

Comment: Can you post a small code sample?

Comment: Are you storing this information for some sort of undo operation?

Comment: For a branching tree search to a depth of `n`: you only need to keep in memory (1) the current best move and `n` nodes.  You do not need to keep the full tree only just the current search/evaluation along 1 branch to depth `n`, this can easily be held on the stack - if you are holding many boards on the heap you are probably doing wrong. (also see alpha-beta algorithm).

Comment: so why not store *moves* in the nodes, and simply construct the board at node *n* from the sequence of moves in the sequence nodes required to get to node *n* from the root?

Comment: @NathanOliver Not specifically no, but it seemed to make sense to store the board information at all of the various nodes.

Comment: @RichardCritten Don't I need to keep information about all of the different Nodes for Monte Carlo such as their win / loss rates?

Comment: @MatthewFennell  Advice -- Memory requirements should have been factored into your design before you write a single line of code.  What may wind up happening is having to scrap a lot, if not all of your current code.

Comment: From a very superficial reading of the Wikipedia article on Monte Carlo search trees, it seems to me that this is a nice theoretical approach, and a horrible practical one. YMMV.

Comment: @PeteBecker MCTS has been succesfully advancing the state of the art in lots of domains in game AI for many years now... so no, it is not a horrible practical approach.

Answer (score 2):

Typical implementations of Monte-Carlo Tree Search (MCTS) do not use any tricks to explicitly avoid running out of memory. In theory, if you keep on simulating, you are indeed going to run out of memory, but this should typically take much more than simply a few thousand simulations as you mentioned in the OP.

Now, most implementations of MCTS only expand the tree by one node per simulation. The code you posted looks like it is adding `b` nodes to the tree per simulation, where `b` is the branching factor (number of children). So that's something you could look into changing.

Furthermore, you could have a look at what you store in the Board class, and make sure you really only have what's necessary there and nothing more. Just the game state's data, and nothing more. For example, make sure you don't have any data in there that is only necessary for a GUI (that's a mistake I made myself years ago).

If you still have issues with memory after looking into these two points, you could consider the suggestion of jaggedSpire's comment. You could store moves instead of board states, and re-construct board states as you run through the nodes in simulations. This will significantly reduce your memory consumption, but also increase the processing time per simulation. This can result in a weaker player if you only have a limited amount of thinking time per turn.

Finally, considering you're doing manual memory management with the `new` operations I see in the code you posted, there is always the possibility that you forgot about a matching `delete` somewhere and have a memory leak. If you still have memory issues with just a few thousand simulations after looking into the points above, this is the most likely cause, because MCTS really shouldn't run into memory issues until you reach much higher simulation counts than a few thousand.

Comment: I have managed to fix the memory leak of creating multiple board objects and as you mentioned now do what jaggedSpire mentioned about just storing the actions. My general approach to the MCTS is to start at the root, if it has been expanded then select the correct child based on it's Upper Confidence Bound. If it hasn't been expanded then expand it and play random simulations until the end of the game.

Comment: But I do have an issue that in each move from the computer it generates a large number of *NEW* nodes, but these are kept in memory after each move, so as the game progresses the memory gets clogged up with the old node information, just I'm not really sure how to free up that memory

Comment: @MatthewFennell Do you mean that the memory usage increases because you don't clean up the search tree after making an actual move in the ''real'' game? If so, yes, you need to make sure to delete the entire search tree after making an actual move in the real game. Alternatively, you can set the node at depth 2 corresponding to one move u made, plus one move the opponent made, as new root node. Then you still need to make sure to delete the nodes above that new root, and the unreachable descendents below those nodes

Comment: for that last point, on reusing the search tree, see http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6731713 and https://dke.maastrichtuniversity.nl/m.winands/documents/CIG2016_GVGAI.pdf . It's gonna be less useful in a two-player game than in those single-player games though

Comment: ~Dennis Soemers - Yeah I mean after making a move in the "real" game. Thing is all of those old nodes were created by calling *NEW Node(...)* in a recursive function, is it still possible to free up the memory that those Nodes are using up?

Comment: @MatthewFennell Sure. To delete the entire tree, you'd probably just want to delete the root node, and in the destructor of the Node class implement that you also delete the children. Tree Reuse would be more difficult in this case, since you wouldn't necessarily want to delete ALL children. All of this would be much easier with smart pointers instead of manual memory management though.